# Averageifs with Or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have read that this may not be possible/ I am just doing it wrong so I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround (non - VBA) or could correct me? Thanks!

```
Col A has the price of apples and oranges
Col D has apples and Oranges
Col E has the type of fruit (Red, Yellow, Green, Purple)
```

I'm trying to get the average of Col A where Col D is Apples and Col E is either Red or Yellow.

I tried:

```
=SUM(AVERAGEIFS(A:A,D:D,"Apples",E:E,"Red"),AVERAGEIFS(A:A,D:D,"Apples",E:E,"Yellow"))/2
```

But it did not work - anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Than you very much for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,D:D,"Apples",E:E,{"Red","Yellow"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D,"Apples",E:E,{"Red","Yellow"}))
```

Confirm with `Enter`

**Edit** *Comparison of formulas*

1) In this first screenshot all results appear similar:
[image]

2) In this second screenshot I changed cell E8 to purple. Results start to differ:
[image]

3) In this third screenshot it becomes clear there is no result using AVERAGE while there is using SUM/COUNTIFS:
[image]

Comment: The difference in the result with @Jeeped formula is because the average of the group averages will not be the same as the average of all the individuals unless each group has the same number of members.  `SUM/COUNT` is the better solution in this situation (and you beat me to it by three minutes).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add OR operations in `AVERAGEIFS` but you can use this (it's an array formula so you'll have to enter it with ctrl + shift + enter):

```
=AVERAGE(IF((D:D="Apples")*((E:E="Yellow")+ (E:E="Red")),A:A))
```

If you don't want to use array formula then (as an alternative to @JvdV's answer), you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A,--(D:D="Apples"), --((E:E="Red")+(E:E="Yellow")))/SUMPRODUCT(--(D:D="Apples"), --((E:E="Red")+(E:E="Yellow")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the response from [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv), you can use AVERAGEIFS directly.

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(A:A, B:B, {"a","c"}))
'for your data
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(A:A,D:D, "Apples", E:E, {"Red","Yellow"}))
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

```
4.00            apples  Red
2.70            oranges Purple
2.13            apples  Purple
2.64            apples  Yellow
3.11            apples  Purple
2.96            apples  Purple
9.44            apples  Yellow
2.07            oranges Red
3.14            oranges Purple
3.58            oranges Yellow
2.44            oranges Red
2.82            apples  Red
2.86            apples  Yellow
2.23            oranges Yellow
1.95            apples  Red
2.37            oranges Yellow
```

The above sample data produces identical results for the following:

```
=AVERAGE(A2,A5,A8,A13,A14,A16)
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(A:A,D:D,"apples",E:E,{"red","yellow"}))
=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A, D:D, "apples", E:E, {"red","yellow"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D, "apples", E:E, {"red","yellow"}))
```

[image]

However when there are a different number of matches in the { OR } criteria then there are bad results.

```
4.00            apples  Red
2.70            oranges Purple
2.13            apples  Purple
2.64            apples  Yellow
3.11            apples  Purple
2.96            apples  Purple
9.44            apples  Yellow
2.07            apples  Red
3.14            oranges Purple
3.58            oranges Yellow
2.44            oranges Red
2.82            apples  Red
2.86            apples  Yellow
2.23            oranges Yellow
1.95            apples  Red
2.37            oranges Yellow
```

[image]

Comment: I think if you have two sets of criteria, with different numbers of possibilities in each, the `AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(….` will return an incorrect result.  eg. two `Red Apple` and three `Yellow Apple` will return the average of each in the array.  Since they don't have the same number of members, the average of the averages will not be the same as the average of all red and yellow apples.

Comment: @Jeeped, not sure why but but im getting differenct results applying both mine and your formula at times. I'll add an example in my answer. Edit: I guess Ron Rosenfeld just explained :)

Comment: My bad. The lack of sample data forced me to make up my own and I may have returned premature results. I'll dive into this a bit deeper.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: @JvdV - I could not reproduce the discrepancy. See my addendum above.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - See my addendum above.

Comment: I'm on my way out right now so can't double check. However it looks like you have the same number of red apples snd yellow apples. Set up a group where you have different numbers of red and yellow apples

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Yes, different number of matches in the { OR } produces disparate results. I'll update above.

Comment: @Jeeped, I have cross-checked. Please see results in my edited answer.